# Upload image to Swift from Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, object-storage

I have a problem related with uploading images directly to object storage Swift, using Django Rest Framework.

Most of tutorials present simple upload images to /media/ directory in localhost, but this option is not going to fit in my project.

Tried use django-storage-swift -  https://github.com/blacktorn/django-storage-swift . While doing requests using httpie, I received in 50% of requests an error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:600)
[06/Jun/2017 13:03:01] "POST /api/processing_raw_files/ HTTP/1.1" 500 24946
```

This makes, that only half of uploading files will be in fact sending to the cloud.

I am working on

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Python 3.4.3
- Django 1.11
- djangorestframework 3.6.2
- django-storage-swift 1.2.16

Do you know any other possibility how can I upload images using swift and django rest? Or did you face with ssl error utilizing django-storage-swift?

Comment: The files related to the errors, are they by any change larger than the files which do get uploaded?

Comment: @dentemm the tested images have similar weight, so we can exclude that. What might helps is apt-get upgrade, and reinstall libssl1, libssl-dev, zlib1g-dev. This approach solved the issue in my case!